# Selenium Try Catch Python [Drag and Drop File Upload]

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing

I am  trying to write a code that checks wheather a website has a drag and drop functionality. To achieve that, I am first retrieving the all elements of the website and try to upload a file with a drag and drop. However when I get the invalid id for an drag and drop I am getting a `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: <unknown>: Element not interactablet` exception. I tried to solve it with try/catch block but it still did not work.

```
   ids = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id]')
    
    counter = 0 
    for ii in ids:
        print(ii,ii.get_attribute('id'))
        driver.find_element_by_id(ii.get_attribute('id'))
        dropzone = driver.find_element_by_id(ii.get_attribute('id'))
        try:
            dropzone.drop_files("/temp/pythonSelenium/test.txt")
    
        except ElementNotInteractableException:
            continue
```

Comment: Here, the exception raised might be different than what you are trying to catch. That may be causing to skip your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably catching the wrong error. The error message says:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: <unknown>: Element not interactable
```

As you can see, the error message source is `WebDriverException` and not `ElementNotInteractableException`. It is a bit confusing, but you have to look for the source if you want to catch an error.

So in order to catch the error you have to change your code to this:

```
try:
    dropzone.drop_files("/temp/pythonSelenium/test.txt")

except WebDriverException:
    continue
```